# Using a JS while loop to draw several images to the canvas in different locations

Tags: math, javascript

I have the following JS loop, which I'm using to draw several images to an HTML5 canvas:

```
while(arrayIteration < allImagesArray.length){
        context.drawImage(allImagesArray[arrayIteration], imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight); /*Declare variables for image height and width, so it can be accessed elsewhere */
        allImagesArray[arrayIteration].setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
        console.log(arrayIteration); /*Display the current array position that's being drawn */
        arrayIteration = arrayIteration+1;
        /*Now try changing the values of imageX & imageY so that the next image is drawn to a 
        different location*/
        imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*950);
        imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*350);

    }
```

I had hoped that by defining the values of my 'imageX' and 'imageY' variables within the loop, that they might be given a different value by the

```
'Math.random()'
```

function with each iteration of the loop, and so draw each image in a different location. I know that this wouldn't necessarily mean that no images would overlap at all, however, currently they are all being drawn to exactly the same location, so that you have to drag the top image to another location to be able to see the one underneath, etc.

Any idea how I can ensure that my 'imageX' and 'imageY' variables have a different value with each iteration of the loop?

**Edit**

This is the full code for my index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  canvas{
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
    background:#F5F5F5;
  }
</style>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="kinetic.js"></script>
<script src="drawdescriptionboxes.js"></script>
<script src="drawLevelOneElements.js"></script>
<script src="startgamedrawgameelementsdrawstartbutton.js"></script>
<script>
/*Add the game elements' global variables */
var currentLevel = 1;
var totalLevels = 3;
var currentScore = 0;
var currentScorePositionX = 950;
var currentScorePositionY = 10;

/*Add code to draw images to random locations here */
    //var imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*950);
    //var imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*450);

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: "container",
      width: 1000,
      height: 500
    });
    var imagesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var canvas = imagesLayer.getCanvas();
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    console.log("Foo ");

/*Load the images from the HTML into the JavaScript */
function loadImages(sources, callback){
    var imagesDir = "";
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;

    //console.log("length " + sources.length);
    for (var src in sources){
        numImages++;
        }
    //console.log("Num Images " + numImages);

    var index=0;
    console.log("length " + sources.length);
    for (index=0;index < numImages ;index++){
        console.log(index);
        images[index] = new Image();
        images[index].src = sources[index];
        console.log("Adding " + sources[index]);
        callback(images[index]);
        console.log("images array length = " + images.length);
        }

    stage.add(imagesLayer); // should only be added once!!
    }

/*Function to check whether the item being dragged is near its description box */
function isNearDescriptionBox(itemImage, descriptionBox){
    var ii = itemImage;
    var db = descriptionBox;
    if(ii.attrs.x > db.x - 20 && ii.attrs.x < db.x + 20 && ii.attrs.y > db.y - 20 && ii.attrs.y < db.y +20){
        return true;
        }else{
        return false;
        }
    }

/* This function draws the game elements */
function drawGameElements(){
    /* Draw a line for the 'score bar'. */
    context.moveTo(0, 25);
    context.lineTo(1000, 25);
    context.stroke();

    /* Draw current level/ total levels on the left, and current score on the right. */
    context.font = "11pt Calibri"; /* Text font & size */
    context.strokeStyle = "black"; /* Font colour */
    context.strokeText(currentLevel + "/" + totalLevels, 10, 15);
    context.strokeText(currentScore, 750, 15);
    }

function initStage(images){
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: 1000,
        height: 500
        });
    var descriptionLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    //var imagesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var allImages = [];
    var currentScore = 0;

    var descriptionBoxes = {
        assetsDescriptionBox: {
            x: 70,
            y: 400
            },
        liabilitiesDescriptionBox: {
            x: 300,
            y: 400
            },
        incomeDescriptionBox: {
            x: 530,
            y: 400
            },
        expenditureDescriptionBox: {
            x: 760,
            y: 400
            },
        };

    /*Code to detect whether image has been dragged to correct description box */
    for (var key in sources){
        /*Anonymous function to induce scope */
        (function(){
            var privateKey = key;
            var imageSource = sources[key];

            /*Check if image has been dragged to the correct box, and add it to that box's
                array and remove from canvas if it has */
            canvasImage.on("dragend", function(){
                var descriptionBox = descriptionBoxes[privateKey];
                if(!canvasImage.inRightPlace && isNearDescriptionBox(itemImage, descriptionBox)){
                    context.remove(canvasImage);
                    /*Will need to add a line in here to add the image to the box's array */
                    }
                })

            })();
        }

    }

function drawImage(imageObj) {
    //var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      // puts the image in teh middle of the canvas
      x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      draggable: true
    });

    // add cursor styling
    canvasImage.on('mouseover', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    canvasImage.on('mouseout', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    imagesLayer.add(canvasImage);
}

/*This code loads the images to the canvas when the browser window loads */
window.onload = function(){
    var sources = {};
        sources[0] = document.getElementById("building").src,
        sources[1] = document.getElementById("chair").src,
        sources[2] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
        sources[3] = document.getElementById("food").src,
        sources[4] = document.getElementById("fridge").src,
        sources[5] = document.getElementById("land").src,
        sources[6] = document.getElementById("money").src,
        sources[7] = document.getElementById("oven").src,
        sources[8] = document.getElementById("table").src,
        sources[9] = document.getElementById("van").src,

        sources[10] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
        sources[11] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
        sources[12] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
        sources[13] = document.getElementById("franchiseFee").src,
        sources[14] = document.getElementById("wages").src,

        sources[15] = document.getElementById("admin").src,
        sources[16] = document.getElementById("cleaners").src,
        sources[17] = document.getElementById("electricity").src,
        sources[18] = document.getElementById("insurance").src,
        sources[19] = document.getElementById("manager").src,
        sources[20] = document.getElementById("rates").src,
        sources[21] = document.getElementById("training").src,
        sources[22] = document.getElementById("water").src,

        sources[23] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
        sources[24] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
        sources[25] = document.getElementById("drink").src,

        sources[26] = document.getElementById("creditors").src,
        sources[27] = document.getElementById("electricity").src,
        sources[28] = document.getElementById("food").src,
        sources[29] = document.getElementById("hirePurchase").src,
        sources[30] = document.getElementById("loan").src,
        sources[31] = document.getElementById("overdraft").src,
        sources[32] = document.getElementById("payeTax").src,
        sources[33] = document.getElementById("tax").src

    loadImages(sources, drawImage);
    drawGameElements();
    drawDescriptionBoxes();
    };


    </script>


</head>
<body>

<section hidden>
<img id="startButton" src="images/startButton.png" alt="Start Button" width="179" height="180" href="javascript:drawLevelOneElements();"/>
<img id="box" src="images/box.png" alt="box.png" alt="Description Box" width="100" height="50" />

<img id="building" src="images/assets/building.png" alt="Asset" />
<img id="chair" src="images/assets/chair.gif" alt="Asset" />
<img id="drink" src="images/assets/drink.jpg" alt="Asset" />
<img id="food" src = "images/assets/food.gif" alt="Asset"/>
```

In the 'body' tags of this page, I have about 40 images, all included using img tags like this:

```
<img id="building" src="images/assets/building.png" alt="Asset" />
<img id="chair" src="images/assets/chair.gif" alt="Asset" />
<img id="drink" src="images/assets/drink.jpg" alt="Asset" />
<img id="food" src = "images/assets/food.gif" alt="Asset"/>
```

and these are the ones I'm referring to in the JavaScript, and adding to the 'sources' array.

My drawleveloneelements.js file, which is where the code I originally posted in my question comes from, looks like this:

```
    function drawLevelOneElements(){
    /*First, clear the canvas */ 
    context.clearRect(0, 0, myGameCanvas.width, myGameCanvas.height);
    /*This line clears all of the elements that were previously drawn on the canvas. */
    /*Then redraw the game elements */
    drawGameElements(); 
    /*Call the function to enable drag and drop */
    canvasState(document.getElementById('gameCanvas'));

    /*Create the four description areas, and place them near the bottom of the canvas */
    /*Create boxes with rounded corners for the description areas */
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawDescriptionArea = function(x, y, width, height, radius, stroke){
        if(typeof stroke == "undefined" ){
            stroke = true;
        }
        if(typeof radius === "undefined"){
            radius = 5;
        }
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x + radius, y);
        this.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
        this.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
        this.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
        this.lineTo(x, y + radius);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
        this.closePath();
        if(stroke){
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    context.drawDescriptionArea(70, 400, 120, 70);
    context.font = '25pt Calibri';
    context.strokeText('Asset', 90, 440);

    context.drawDescriptionArea(300, 400, 120, 70);
    context.strokeText('Liability', 310, 440);

    context.drawDescriptionArea(540, 400, 120, 70);
    context.strokeText('Income', 550, 440);

    context.drawDescriptionArea(750, 400, 180, 70);
    context.strokeText('Expenditure', 760, 440);

    /*Now draw the images to the canvas */
    /*First, create variables for the x & y coordinates of the image that will be drawn.
    the x & y coordinates should hold random numbers, so that the images will be 
    drawn in random locations on the canvas.*/
    //var imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    //var imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    var imageWidth = 50;
    var imageHeight = 50;

    /*Create a 'table' of positions that the images will be drawn to */
    //var imagePositionsX = [20, 80, 140, 200, 260, 320, 380, 440, 500, 560];
    //var imagePositionsY = [20, 60, 100, 140, 180, 220, 260, 300, 340, 380];

    /*Draw all images from assetsImageArray */
    /*Use a while loop to loop through the array, get each item and draw it. */
    var arrayIteration = 0;
    console.log('All Images Array length: ' + allImagesArray.length); /*Display the length of the array in the console, to check it's holding the correct number of images. */
    while(arrayIteration < allImagesArray.length){
        context.drawImage(allImagesArray[arrayIteration], imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight); /*Declare variables for image height and width, so it can be accessed elsewhere */
        allImagesArray[arrayIteration].setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
        console.log(arrayIteration); /*Display the current array position that's being drawn */
        arrayIteration = arrayIteration+1;
        /*Now try changing the values of imageX & imageY so that the next image is drawn to a 
        different location*/
        imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*950);
        imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*350);

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything to indicate that this shouldn't work as intended.

Comment: Where did you declare and initialize the variables? Please post the whole code. Seems to me you get an error because they're undefined in the first turn.

Comment: Please notice that `.setAttribute('draggable', 'true')` won't make the canvas-drawn images draggable, but only HTML elements.

Comment: I'm using a JS library called KineticJS- which is how that line does make the images draggable. I've declared and initialized the variables inside some script tags in my HTML page, that code has come from a JS file I've written. Would it be worth commenting out the line in my HTML that's declared them, and declare them within that function?

Comment: I tried commenting out the lines declaring those variables in the index.html script tags, but that hasn't made a difference to what's happening on screen- the images that are drawn are only drawn by the code that I've posted, there's no other parts of code involved in drawing them to the canvas.

Comment: @someone2088: Really? The demo codes of the tutorials on [images](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-image-tutorial/) and [drag'n'drop](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/) look very different to me.

Comment: @someone2088: I did not want you to comment them out, but to show them to us.

Comment: I'll post the full code now

Comment: Full code posted as requested

Comment: I can't see why this wouldn't work. But don't you need to use `Kinectic.Image()` to make a draggable image? If you haven't already, try (i) logging the values of imagex and imagey to check they're changing and (ii) commenting out `allImagesArray[arrayIteration].setAttribute('draggable', 'true')` in case that is somehow affecting the position.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you're using a mix of KineticJS and ordinary canvas manipulation; the trouble would be that KineticJS refreshes the canvas in order to animate (e.g. dragging and dropping) and loses the non-Kinetic objects you've drawn there.

Comment: I'm using a version of the Kinetic JS library that I've saved locally, and have edited it to stop it 'refreshing' or 'clearing' the canvas each time a function is called that draws something to the canvas, as I was having a problem with the game elements being drawn, and then removed when the images were drawn to the canvas, since they were called by separate functions. I also had a problem with drawing images to the canvas from an array- where only the last image in the array would be displayed, since the library would clear the canvas before drawing each image,

Comment: So after altering the library, I now have everything being drawn to the canvas by several functions, without clearing the canvas at all, unless I tell it to with the code I've written in my functions.

Comment: What I've changed in the library also stops the canvas being refreshed when moving objects around with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first, don't use *while*; use for. Try this.

```
for(var arrayIteration = 0, arraylen = allImagesArray.length; arrayIteration < arraylen; arrayIteration++){
        /*Movethe var initialization & setting to the top of the loop*/
        var imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*950);
        var imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*350);            
        context.drawImage(allImagesArray[arrayIteration], imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight); /*...*/
        allImagesArray[arrayIteration].setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
        console.log(arrayIteration); /*... */
}
```